# Nginx: maintenance mode with "is a developer" check

Tags: nginx, website, maintenance

It's much [variants](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=nginx%20maintenance%20mode) described in Internet how to display maintenance page with nginx. But I didn't find the solution to check if user is a developer and not to display maintenance page for developers.

I use try_files, which [does't works](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=nginx%20if%20try_files) as I need after any IF-section was entered. So I made my own solution, which I want to share. It works in any configuration with try_files, proxy and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `http` section (out of any `server` section) check the user if he is a developer:

   ```
   map $http_cookie $isDevHack {
       default "";
       ~DEVELOPER_SECRET=1010 "/non-existed-location";
   }
   ```

   User is a developer if he had `DEVELOPER_SECRET` with `1010` value in this case. This map is shared for all servers in config.
2. Append `server` section with 503-error handler:

   ```
   error_page 503 @maintenance;
   location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance-mode.html break;
   }
   ```

   `maintenane-mode.html` is a page to display for non-developer users in maintenance mode. File path is relative to `document_root` of current `server`.
3. In `location` sections, which must be protected in maintenance mode, add before any normal-mode rules:

   ```
   if (-f "$isDevHack/home/site-home/maintenance") {
       return 503;
   }
   ```

   If current user is a developer, checked file name will be prepended with `/non-existed-location` prefix and `if` will never be entered.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fairly simple server setup for which the configuration at the end of the answer will do the following:

1. If a file named `MAINTENANCE` exists one level above the root, then the server will be in maintenance mode. (This is the `-f` test).
2. Except that if there exist a cookie named `foo_dev` with the value `secret!`, the check described above will be bypassed and nginx will serve the data as if the server were not in maintenance mode. (This is the `$cookie_foo_dev = "secret!"` test.)

I've tried with some `try_files` settings and did not run into any issue.

Here is the configuration.

```
server {
    # ... omitted stuff that does not pertain to the solution ...

    root <some path>;

    if ($cookie_foo_dev = "secret!") {
        break;
    }

    if ( -f $document_root/../MAINTENANCE) {
       return 503;
    }

    error_page 503 @maintenance;
    location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

All incoming connections are required to use HTTPS so the cookie never goes in plain text over the Internet.

I've also set the server to which nginx forwards the requests to display a big fat warning if the cookie `foo_dev` is set so that I don't mistakenly forget that the site is in maintenance mode.